# How does nat bench work ? I reach 30,34TB using nats bench but I don't understand why

Tags: nats.io

I'm new to NATS, I first bench the NATS with nats-bench

```
quanlm@quanlm2:~/go/src/github.com/nats-io/nats.go/examples/nats-bench$ go run main.go -np 1 -n 100000000 -ms 1600000 -csv test foo
Starting benchmark [msgs=100000000, msgsize=1600000, pubs=1, subs=0]
Pub stats: 20,848,474 msgs/sec ~ 30.34 TB/sec
Saved metric data in csv file test
```

My computer setup: 
"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz CPU(s):            16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           16
CPU MHz:             2199.996"
Memory: 24GB
SSD

I have no idea how nat-bench work to reach that 30.34 TB/sec

Is this just a bug or I did somethings wrong ?

Btw: what does msgsize count in: bits/byte ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. You are publishing 100 million messages, each of 1600000 bytes (about 1.5 MB). The bench utility reports that it was able to send 20,848,474 messages per second, and since one message is 1600000 bytes, that is: 20,848,474 * 1600000 = 33357558400000 bytes per second, which is about 30.34 TB per second.

Comment: uhm yeah thanks for the caculation but I don't understand how it can give that speed 
It just send the messages not the data in it :/ ?